# Implementing Text Watcher for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an EditText. When i click on it, it becomes focusable. I will type the input text to be entered into the EditText. I want to implement a listener for EditText, so that when i stop typing, it should automatically save that text into the database instead of having a button. How to have a listener for EditText to listen that typing is stopped or not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

set edittext imeOption

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

By using something like this,

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // Specify your database function here.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `OnEditorActionListener` interface to avoid the anonymous inner class.

Comment: You can also close the virtual keyboard after Done is clicked by returning false instead of returning true.

Answer (score 62):

Try like this.

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "Set text xyz");
et.setText("xyz");

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("TextWatcherTest", "afterTextChanged:\t" +s.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

**Add This to your editText**

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **[debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)** operator of Rx java.

```
subject.debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .map(yourString -> {
                           // save to db
                        }
                        return "";
                    })
                    .subscribe()
```

Here you can define time limit , after how much time you want it to get saved in db.