# How can I change color state of an ImageView based on an empty test of an EditText line?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imageview, android-drawable

When the `EditText` line is blank (the default), I'd like the `ImageView` icon color to be white.

When the icon is pressed, I'd like the color to be black and then revert back to white because the press clears the `EditText` line, so it would then again be empty.

With the `ImageView`, I first set `src` equal to a white `drawable`.  Any thoughts on how to switch the color state based on the length test of the `EditText` line?

Comment: for edittext you need to implement textwatcher to listen to the textchanges. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699569/implementing-text-watcher-for-edittext

Comment: so add code after onTextChanged that will change the setBackgroundColor?

Comment: better do it in `afterTextChanged` see the 2nd answer in link provided. not the accepted answer. and to change color on button click, you just need to set selector. so that when its state changes, relative drawable will be selected by itself. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Comment: ok thanks I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too exactly sure what the question is asking for, I got confused when you brought in ImageView and hover because I don't believe phones support the onHoverListener as well.. Do you mean changing the EditText accent color when you click on it to type something? If so it will be under the *colors.xml-->colorAccent*

Also if you mean to change an images background color

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(EditText.getText().toString()));
        }
```

Hopefully I provided you with some help to continue your project.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.  I guess for hover I was thinking of mouse cursor since I've been developing with an emulator.  I will edit my answer to remove hover reference.  For the color change white to black and then back to white, should I be removing the "android:src="drawable/..." line from my xml layout file and then setBackgroundColor as you suggest programmatically in the Activity file?

Comment: What I am imagining is that you have an ImageView and a EditText, if you have an emty EditText the ImageView would be white. When the EditText is clicked on the ImageView would change to black?

Comment: Almost.  EditText line starts out empty and icon is white.  When the user inputs data onto the EditText line then the line is not longer blank, so I'd like the ImageView to change to the color black.

Answer (score 0):

To update icon if textview empty, check [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input) with `addTextChangedListener()` then

```
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.i("Text", charSequence + "");
                if(charSequence.length()==0)
                    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_unpressed);
                else
                    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            }
```

and to change imagebutton background follow its state [How to set image button backgroundimage for different state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state) with "create an xml in your drawable"

If you want to keep color of icon remain black after pressed, just override onClick() by

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Would those answers apply to an ImageView as well as the button you suggest?

Comment: No for ImageView. ImageView and ImageButton just difference by onClick action basically. You should use ImageButton/Button in this case

Comment: Ok I will research the onClick difference but why are you recommending using an ImageButton rather than an ImageView?

Comment: Because of "When the icon is pressed"...ImageButton supported it and you could customize its drawable via xml also