# How do I actively check if EditText field is null or not?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I am designing a text based game and I want it so that when a user enters something in an EditText field, other items on screen update accordingly. I tried doing the following in the onCreate method to no avail (probably because that method is only called when the activity is first created).

How do I actively check if a user inputted something in the field without them pressing a button and only by them typing something in the field?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Typeface myTypeface;
    TextView myTextView;

    myTypeface= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/script.ttf");



    EditText players = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_players);

    //while(players.getText().toString().matches("")) {}

    if(!players.getText().toString().matches(""))
        myTextView.setText(players.getText().toString()); //this is just to debug if it is actually working
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a TextWatcher on the field via addTextChangedListener.

Comment: Should I put that in the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

You can find here the exact [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699569/implementing-text-watcher-for-edittext) with solution.

Simply use `TextWatcher` and implement its `onTextChanged()` where you'll be able to catch every change to the edit text.

Comment: Sorry beginner here, would I do this in the onCreate method as well?