# Unable to retrieve input text from EditText in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, kotlin-android-extensions

I am unable to retrieve the input text from a EditText in Android.
Here's my code:

```
package com.example.fragments2

import ...
import com.example.fragments2.databinding.FragmentLoginPageBinding
class LoginPage : Fragment()
{

    lateinit var loginId:EditText
    lateinit var password:EditText
    lateinit var loginButton:Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?

        {
            var binding:FragmentLoginPageBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_login_page,container,false)
            var view  = binding.root
            loginId = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_userid)
            password = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_password)
            loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button_login)

            val text1: String = loginId.text.toString()
            val text2:String = password.text.toString()

        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
               Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(LoginPageDirections.actionLoginPageToMainPage(text1,text2))
               Toast.makeText(context,text1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //<-- shows empty string
           }

            return view
        }


}
```

The value of Text1, Text2 always remains **""** .
What's wrong in this code?

Comment: You already check if `var view  = binding.root` is returning correctely?

Comment: @Augusto Yeah, It's returning the correct View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that click callback ins´t take the correct instance of yours `TextViews`. Try get these values inside click button:

```
class LoginPage : Fragment()
{

    lateinit var loginId:EditText
    lateinit var password:EditText
    lateinit var loginButton:Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?

        {
            var binding:FragmentLoginPageBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_login_page,container,false)
            var view  = binding.root
            loginId = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_userid)
            password = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_password)
            loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button_login)

            loginButton.setOnClickListener {
                val text1: String = loginId.text.toString()
                val text2: String = password.text.toString()
                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(LoginPageDirections.actionLoginPageToMainPage(text1,text2))
                Toast.makeText(context,text1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //<-- shows empty string
           }

           return view
        }
}
```

**Note:** Maybe you must call the `Toast.makeText` with `runOnUiMainThread()`. It's been some time since I've done this.

```
this.runOnUiThread {
     Toast.makeText(context,text1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //<-- shows empty string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text1 and text2 always remain values you assign them in the beginning.
If you want to get the text of the editText, you can directly request it `loginId.text.toString()`. 
Otherwise, you can create `val text1: String = ""` in the beginning of the class. But to update it, you need to do this inside of `TextWatcher`.
Take a look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699569/implementing-text-watcher-for-edittext)

The issue of your code is that onCreateView invokes only when Fragment initialized. But you need to update values every time your text changes.