# Set all items to a listview from a file .txt (ArrayList) what contains textview value [Android Java]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I want after a button `onClick` `generate1()` show all items from my `Arraylist(.txt`) contains `Edittext` value.

I am a beginner in android java programming.

This is my `onClick` Method generate1():

```
    public void generate1(View view) throws IOException {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        BufferedReader br = null;

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("themen.txt")));
        String word;
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ls.add(word);
        }
        br.close();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ls);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (String e : ls){
           if (e.toLowerCase().contains(editText.getText().toString())){
              //???? some toDO ???? (if i do here System.out.println(e); its work, but i want the Items to a listview!! 
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when iterating for-loop, add items to your array list `ls`, after that you need to refresh your adapter with new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create two global ArrayList .first you named 'ls' for all results.second i call 'lsFiltered' for filtered results;
then...

**change this**

```
for (String e : ls){
       if (e.toLowerCase().contains(editText.getText().toString())){
          //???? some toDO ???? (if i do here System.out.println(e); its work, but i want the Items to a listview!! 
       }
    }
```

**to this**

```
for (int i = 0; i <ls.size() ; i++) {
        if (e.toLowerCase().contains(editText.getText().toString())){
            lsFiltered.add(ls.get(i));
        }
}
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lsFiltered);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i let the first for(e)  and add the second for(i) then i delete the first adapter and add just the adapter from u. But its not working. i see all the items from my Arraylist(.txt)

Comment: you should put this for in afterTextChanged(Editable s) of edittext if you want to filter while user entering characters in edittext.

Comment: if you dont know what is afterTextChanged(Editable s) read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39673208/10554417

Comment: I tried but unfortunately without success. Thks for triying to help me Salar

Comment: Never give up :) ... can u look at my new method, its worked now but i think i forgot something. thks

Comment: In your new method you use for and while together.this is why it repeats 10 times.remove for and see if it resolves!

Comment: Yes its worked after i delete while() thks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

First create an adapter class like this:

```
public class DemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public DemoAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

        if (view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,viewGroup,false);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(myViewHolder);
        } else {
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        myViewHolder.myTv.setText(data.get(i));

        return view;
    }


    class MyViewHolder{
        TextView myTv;

        public MyViewHolder(View item){
            myTv = item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your **generate1** method iniialize it like this:

```
DemoAdapter adapter = DemoAdapter(this,ls);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: in the last line of the DemoAdapter class : item.findViewById(android.R.id.editText)   i get can not resolve symbol 'editText'....i change bevor EditText mytv;

Comment: as you are using simple_list_item_1, you have to use text1 as this is its item, you can also make your own layout and then access your widget accordingly.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately without success. Thks for triying to help me Soumik

Comment: Never give up :) ... can u look at my new method, its worked now but i think i forgot something. thks

Comment: Really appreciate your try, the value is showing 10 times because everytime after setting one value it is not going out of the while loop, it is incrementing its value by 1 and then again setting same value in the next position until its full size. So, you just have to do this:

`for (int j=0; j<ls.size();j++) {
                    ls2.add(j,ls.get(j));           
        }
    //for checking only
    System.out.println(ls2);`

Comment: Thks a lot, its already worked. i have delete the while() and let just the for each().

Answer (score 0):

public void generate1(View view) throws IOException {

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ls2 = new ArrayList<>();

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    BufferedReader br = null;

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("themen.txt")));
        String word;
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ls.add(word);
        }
        br.close();
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    for (String e : ls) {

           int i = 0;
            while (i<ls.size()){

               if (e.toLowerCase().contains(editText.getText().toString())) {

                    ls2.add(i,e);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ls2);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

}
```

i found another way and its worked :D, but the result in the listview is everytime viewed 10 times!!?? 
I forgot something??